# Transcribing songs using just iPhone

Tags: software

I want to transcribe songs by ear using just an iPhone (without any musical instrument). Somebody knows one app that could help me? The app must be able to play music from my song library and let me write something (chords, sheet music or tabs).

I wish something like [capo](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/capo/id386963803?mt=8) with [guitar pro](https://itunes.apple.com/br/app/guitar-pro/id400666114?mt=8) capabilities on the same app. Do you know an app with these features?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, the options are a bit limited. However, there is an app that will soon be available from Think Music Technology that looks pretty incredible. You can look at those details [here](http://www.thinkmusictechnology.com/).